# Read multiple sheets in multiple excel files using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tensorflow

I am trying to make a list using pandas before putting all data sets into 2D convolution layers.

And I was able to merge all data in the multiple excel files as a list.

However, the code only reads one chosen sheet name in the multiple excel files.

For example, I have 7 sheets in each excel file; named as 'gpascore1', 'gpascore2', 'gpascore3', 'gpascore4', 'gpascore5', 'gpascore6', 'gpascore7'.

And each sheet has 4 rows and 425 columns like

[image]

As shown below, you can see the code.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'gpascore1') # Read only one chosen sheet available -> 
                                           gpascore1 is a sheet name.
    df = df.append(data)                 # But there are 6 more sheets and I would like 
                                           to read data from all of the sheets

data_y = df['admit'].values
data_x = []

for i, rows in df.iterrows():
    data_x.append([rows['gre'], rows['gpa'], rows['rank']])

df=df.dropna()
df.count()
```

Then, I got the result as below.

[image]

This is because the data from the 'gpascore1' sheet in 3 excel files were merged.

But, I want to read the data of 6 more sheets in the excel files.

Could anyone help me to find out the answer, please?

Thank you

===============<Updated code & errors>==================================

Thank you for the answers and I revised the read_excel() as

```
 data = pd.read_excel(f, 'gpascore1') to
 data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
```

But, I have key errors like below.

[image]

Could you give me any suggestions for this issue, please?

Thank you

Comment: if you pass `sheet_name = None` `pd.read_excel` will return a a dictionary of dataframes where the key is the sheet name

Comment: You can loop over sheet names by creating a list

Comment: Thank you for the answer Manakin and tried to change the code, but it shows some key error issues, so I posted the updated errors. Could you check what is going on, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found this question under the tag of 'tensorflow'.  That's hilarious.  Ok, so you want to merge all Excel sheets into one dataframe?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

import glob
glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    
type(all_data)
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer. I actually tried to make several data frames for the 3d input shape for the convolution layer. With a single sheet of excel data, I can get the 2d type shape of data set for the training and validation data set. However, I would like to get multiple data frames with several sheets in excel. So, I can put the 3d input shape of data set to the 1d convolution layer.

Comment: Then, as you can see the captured image for data set in the post, there are 1 validation data (which is an 'admit') and 3 training data (which are 'gre', 'gpa', and 'rank'). And I have 7 more sheet in the same excel file (gpascore01). Actually, I manually merged all excel files (gpascore01, 02, 03) together and arranged all data set in a single excel file, which is a 'gpascore01'.

Comment: I asked the question in the following link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468568/tensorflow-dimension-issue-valueerror-expected-min-ndim-4-found-ndim-3-full. Hopefully, I would like to get your help plz.