# Tensorflow dimension issue: ValueError: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 3, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a conv1D-based deep learning model to predict graduate school's acceptance status.

Previously, I posted how to preprocess excel data with Pandas library, and thanks to your help, I successfully built a data preprocessing model.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)                

data_y = df.iloc[:,0:1] 
data_x = df.iloc[:,1:2] 

data_x1 = data_x[0:3].to_numpy().tolist() 
data_y1 = data_y[0:3].to_numpy().tolist()

dx = data_x1[0]
dy = data_y1[0]

dt_x1 = dx[0].loc[:,'admit':'rank']
dt_x1 = dt_x1.dropna()

dt_result = dt_x1['admit'].values
dt_training = dt_x1[['gre', 'gpa', 'rank']].values
```

Then, I consecutively used a conv1d layer, maxpooling1d layer, flatten layer and dense layer for the model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dt_training = dt_training.reshape((dt_training.shape[0],3))
dt_result = dt_result.reshape((dt_result.shape[0],1))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', input_shape=(425,4)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 3),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='tanh'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(dt_training, dt_result, epochs = 10)
```

I think it worked properly, but I have a dimension error like below when I fit the model.

[image]
[image]

Is there someone to give me a solution for this error, please?

I suffered from this error for 2 weeks, but I have no idea to solve this issue.

Many thanks.

I almost forgot how the data looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are changes to be made in the preprocessing step you can do that as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
files = os.listdir(path)
print(files)

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True) 
    
df=df.dropna()
Y=df.pop('admit')
dt_result=Y.to_numpy()
X=df
dt_training=X.to_numpy()
```

Reshape the data as follows:

`dt_training = dt_training.reshape((dt_training.shape[0],3, 1))`

and change the input shape to (3,1), as follows

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', input_shape=(3,1))
```

Let us know if the isssue still persists. Thanks!